# Container orchestration with primary and secondary failover

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers, docker-swarm, orchestration

While a primary/secondary "application" (previously master/slave) can be implemented by oneself I was wondering whether this doesn’t come out of the box in a container orchestration management system.

**Requirements:**

- High availability (redundancy) but doesn’t need scaling (capacity).
- Orchestration decides which one is Primary/Secondary (or Alternates (multiples)).
- Container and application (MyApp) knows whether its Primary/Secondary (or Alternates (multiples)).
- Only the primary application (MyApp) is communicating with the service x and the physical device(s).
- Only the primary application (MyApp) forwards the responses to the secondary (with a safe mechanism in place) so that the secondary has all the data/states up to date at all times.
- Both Container/MyApp primary/secondary receive messages from a service (not in picture) so that both are always up to date in case of a failover.
- Both primary/secondary MyApp's should have the same data at any given time (obviously small delay) but only the primary is communicating towards other services.
- Failover should happen within less than a second (e.g. 500ms).

**Design**
[image: designimage]

Though I have left out the details I hope the overall requirements/concept is clear.

**Questions:**

- Is there a container orchestration management that handles primary/secondary application concept?
- Most importantly will my application (MyApp) hosted in the container know when it's in what state (Startup, Sync, Primary, Secondary, PrimaryOnly)?
- How is it best implemented if there is an existing concept?

Did some research but didn't find anything related to primary/secondary application concept where the container knows in which state it's in (Message orchestration to container?).

Comment: By secondary in this case you mean a hot standby? The secondary service does not provide a function unless the primary fails?

Comment: The most common way to get high resiliency is, AFAIK, to have multiple identical services. I.e. peers rather than primary/secondary. Kubernetes can do that. I don't know of any orchestrators that do primary/secondary failover.

Comment: The key point here is speed and latency. Both MyApps should have the same data (in and out) but the request/responses to the physical device should be limited as the device has its limits. There are about 20-80 TCP requests per 100 milliseconds and doubling that would strain the already strained device and network. So multiple identical services that do the same is not an ideal solution and hot stand by i assume  is waiting and wont have the data up to date. Failover is as fast as possible. Maybe 500ms doesnt do it justice.

Comment: Just to point out some more there is not just one device but hundreds of them.